# adding a HtmlGenericControl object mid text from code behind

Tags: c#, html

I am dynamically generating a page from code behind. I have a need to have both

`<span>`

and `<a href>` over certain words.

I have the returned string

```
string  r = "The quick brown fox [jumps]s12 over the [lazy]a15 dog"
```

which I am trying to turn into

The quick brown fox `<span title="lookup12">jumps</span>` over the `<a href="url15""lazy</a>` dog

> `HtmlContainerControl maindiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");`

```
maindiv.innertext = r
```

I am able to add the span to the whole string not just one word

```
HtmlContainerControl sp12 = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
sp12.Attributes.Add("title", "Super Jumping Dog");
sp12.InnerText="jumping";

maindiv.Control.Add(sp12);
```

But just not the selected Text;

Any Ideas would be appreciated;

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What does this mean? `"I am able to add the span to the whole string or just one word, but just not the selected Text;"`

Comment: I don't think you can do what you're wanting to do without splitting the original string into multiple other Generic controls / literal controls, so you can interject your new control. And that means you'll have to use a placeholder and control originally as well. But can't you just write the HTML in your string without using a control?

Comment: I already have a method to spit the string and identify which word needs which action. I just dont know how to get the action added !!!